# reducing an array for sql query

Tags: php, sql, arrays, reduce

i have dynamic fields so i should put column names and values into an array then reducing the array for sql query i use `array_reduce()`

This is for columns:

```
function fscol($k1,$k2)
{
    return $k1 . "," . $k2;
}
$slides_col_reduce = array_reduce($slides_col, 'fscol');
$final_fscol = substr($slides_col_reduce,1);
```

it work fine no matter how many column name i put.

but my problem is with values array:

```
function fslide($v1,$v2)
{
    return "'" . $v1 . ",'" . $v2 . "'";
}
$final_fslide = substr($slides_reduce,0);
```

even when i change `substr` offset it would have extra or less quote base on values. for example:

```
'','Slide_1.jpg','Slide_4.jpg'
```

Or

```
'''','Slide_1.jpg','Slide_2.jpg','Slide_3.jpg','Slide_4.jpg'
```

How can i fix this problem?

**Note:**

This is for SQL column values. So this is the output i want -> 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code.

```
$str_fields = sprintf("'%s'", implode("','", $fields_array));
```

But if your values may have a single quote, you should consider it. In this case, you may use array_map.